# How to override/prevent Maven Install Plugin behavior

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

this is an odd request but here is the scenario. I am writing custom maven plugins that basically manipulate build versions then will install or deploy the modified jar.  The plugin is called both via command line and a build profile.

The plugins all have similar behavior, so the solution will work for all. Currently I am manipulating the project version in memory, via MavenProject.setVersion(newVersion);. This works and builds a local jar with the new version, but once the MavenInstaller executes the newVersion jar is installed in my local repo with the old version information and location. Is there a way I can prevent or override this behavior? The plugin is not using the Maven Installer or Deployer directly, and is just part of the build phase.

The file is executed as: mvn install -Pincrement and the increment profile is associated with the process-sources phase.

EDIT 1: I am looking into overriding the install/deploy lifecycle with a plugin that will basically handle what I plan on doing, while also still handling the normal behavior of install/deploy.
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-override-default-lifecycle.html

EDIT 2: Following Edit 1 I was able to override a default lifecycle, in this case install and deploy with a custom solution. I do not like that it requires a custom package, so packaging tag no longer refers to the true packaging type and requires me to set an additional tag so that I can lookup the type.

Comment: Did you taken a look into the build-number plugin ?

Comment: The build number is calculated separatley, and for this case the behavior differs. The plugin may be executed on a pom with version 1.0-SNAPSHOT, but the plugins actions results in a 1.1 being packaged. The issue is the installer then takes the 1.1 and installs it as 1.0-SNAPSHOT.